# Is there anyway to save the value of a variable iterating through a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Take this dictionary for example,

```
d = {
  1: ["a", "b"],
  2: ["c", "d"],
  3: ["e", 1]
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
for i in d:
    if any(i in j for j in d.values()): # if a key of d exists in any of the lists 
        'add values of i to the list that had i in it'
```

So d would then look like:

```
d = {
  1: ["a", "b"],
  2: ["c", "d"],
  3: ["e", 1, "a", "b"]
}
```

I understand this can be simply done with a nested for loop, but is there any way with list comprehension?

Comment: If the list comprehension is going to be long and/or complicated you're better off just using a nested loop, for readability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do this with a **list comprehension**, however,
this is how I would do it with **nested for-loops**:

#### Code:

```
d = {
  1: ["a", "b"],
  2: ["c", "d"],
  3: ["e", 1]
}

for k,v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        if i in d.keys():
            d[k] = d[k] + d[i]
            
print(d)
```

#### Output:

```
{1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c', 'd'], 3: ['e', 1, 'a', 'b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. There may be a way to do this using a list comprehension but it would be highly esoteric and (potentially) hard to understand.

```
d = {
  1: ["a", "b"],
  2: ["c", "d"],
  3: ["e", 1]
}

for v in d.values():
    for e in v:
        if (_v := d.get(e)):
            v += _v

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c', 'd'], 3: ['e', 1, 'a', 'b']}
```